# Call a list of files in a directory and pass them in a single line

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

In MySQL,
I want to script a process that automatically grabs mysql binlogs (could be any number of logs) and applies them to the mysql server.

```
 `>dir C:\binlogs
               file1
               file2 
               file3 
               file4
  `

` mysqlbinlog utility command is `

    `> mysqlbinlog.exe file1 file2 file3 file4 | mysql -uroot `
```

How do I script this process in using a batch file

An alternative could be:
       `> mysqlbinlog.exe file1 > file.sql`
       `> mysqlbinlog.exe file2 >> file.sql`
       `> mysqlbinlog.exe file3 >> file.sql`
       `> mysqlbinlog.exe file4 >> file.sql`

```
   `> mysql.exe -uroot < file.sql`
```

Just don't know how to script this via batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set filelist=
for %%# in (*) do set filelist=!filelist!"%%#" 
echo %filelist%
```

This script prints all files in the current directory in one line using the following format: `"file1" "file2" "file3"`. There is one trailing space, which shouldn't matter however since the purpose is to use the list as parameters. In case it does, cut off the last character:

```
echo %filelist:~,-1%
```

Comment: Trailing spaces are difficult to spot, so I'd either `for %%# in (*) do (set filelist=!filelist!"%%#" )` or `for %%# in (*) do set filelist=!filelist! "%%#"` and `echo %filelist:~1%`

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it...I'm further close to achieving my script.

Comment: How about if I wanted to call one file at a time in the directory.                       `Shell> mysqlbinlog.exe file1.txt >  file.sql`                                                                       `shell> mysqlbinlog.exe file2.txt >> file.sql`                                                                 `shell> mysqlbinlog.exe file3.txt >> file.sql`                                                                                                                                                                                     'C:\> mysql -uroot < file.sql`

Comment: @primosad You could just use another `for` loop: `for %%# in (*) do mysqlbinlog "%%#"`